# Javascript PopUp Functionality

Tags: java, javascript, html, popup

I spent hundreds of hours writing an HTML5 application.
This application deals with multiple popups and I suddenly ran into a problem when managing them.

My main goal would be bring a blurred popup window to front by focusing it.
I am wondering if this is possible in JavaScript.

If not, could I use java applet in order to gain more functionality on my popup windows. 
Could I perhaps embed Google V8’s engine in order to render my existing HTML5 code in this application?

Comment: What do you mean by "popup"? A new browser window? An alert()? Some framework's Popup widget?

Comment: Are the popups in different tabs?

Comment: HTML5 Application that uses window.open? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you open a window you create a reference to it. You can then use that reference to call focus() on.

```
var foo = window.open( /*params*/ );
foo.focus();
```

Comment: I tried this many times, modern browsers like Google Chrome and Firefox doesn’t seem to support this feature anymore.

Comment: Yeah, modern browsers have a setting which usually disables site's control on window focus by default. It is deliberately so.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html according to this, Window still has a focus() method. Not sure what exactly you're doing, but this should work.

Comment: I found the solution. In order to bring popup window to front, it has to be done on a user click event.